# Webdriver elemento dinámico

Tags: c#, selenium

Estoy realizando un test automatizado, pero en el flujo de la prueba, se abre una ventana nueva a veces, ya que no se muestra siempre, por lo que hace que no finalice el test.

Introduje un `if/else` pero no me funciona, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Calibreo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está claro lo que preguntas. Puedes añadir el codigo y un ejemplo del comportamiento? Mira [ask] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Trata de ampliar un poco más la información para que sea más sencillo ayudarte

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal lo pase a este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153531/selenium-webdriver-despu%C3%A9s-del-trycatch-no-sigue-con-el-siguiente-metodo